# Define/Use a promise in Express POST route on node.js

Tags: node.js, express, promise

I currently have a POST route defined in an Express Node.js application as so:

```
var locationService = require("../app/modules/locationservice.js");

app.post('/createstop', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    locationService.createStop(res, req.body);
});
```

(for this question, please assume the routing in & db works.. my record is created on form submission, it's the response I am struggling with)

In the `locationservice.js` class I then currently have

```
var models  = require('../models');

exports.createStop = function(res, formData) {

    models.location.build({ name: formData.name })
                   .save()
                   .then(function(locationObj) {
                             res.json({ dbResult : locationObj });
                         });

};
```

So as you can see, my route invokes the exported function `CreateStop` which uses the Sequelize persistent layer to insert a record asynchronously, *after which* I can stick the result on the response in the promised `then()`

So at the moment this only works by passing the response object into the `locationservice.js` method and then setting `res.json` in the `then()` there. This is sub-optimal to me with regards to my service classes, and doesn't feel right either.

What I would like to be able to do is "treat" my `createStop` method as a promise/with a callback so I can just return the new location object (or an error) and deal with it in the calling method - as future uses of this method might have a response context/parameter to pass in/be populated.

Therefore in the route I would do something more like:

```
var locationService = require("../app/modules/locationservice.js");

app.post('/createstop', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    locationService.createStop(req.body)
        .then(dataBack) {
            res.json(dataBack); 
        };
});
```

Which means, I could call `createStop` from else where in the future and react to the response in *that* promise handler. But this is currently beyond me. I have done my due diligence research, but some individual expert input on my specific case would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Your `locationservice.js` could look like that

```
exports.createShop = function(data){
    // here I have used create instead of build -> save
    return models.location.create(data).then(function(location){
        // here you return instance of saved location
        return location;
    });
}
```

And then your `post()` method should be like below

```
app.post('/createstop', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    locationService.createShop(req.body).then(function(location){
        // here you access the location created and saved in createShop function
        res.json(location);
    }).catch(function(error){
        // handle the error
    });
});
```

Comment: this worked a treat. thank you. I hadn't thought of returning the whole function.

Comment: In order to perform `.then()` on `createShop` method in route resolver, it is necessary to return a promise from `locationservice.js - createShop` function

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `createStop` function with a promise like so:

```
exports.createStop = function(res, formData) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        models.location.build({ name: formData.name })
                   .save()
                   .then(function(locationObj) {
                             resolve({ dbResult : locationObj });
                   });

                   //in case of error, call reject();
    });
};
```

This will allow you to use the `.then` after the createStop within your router.

Comment: Could you possibly replace the ES6 => with old school markup? I can't quite get this working in my code and it's throwing me!!